# Animated GIFs in questions

Tags: discussion, images, hyperlinks

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503219/how-do-you-find-the-area-of-this-egg) post come up during review, and my lizard brain yelling ANIMATED GIF ARGH DIE IN A FIRE overcame any rational response.  I'm not sure I've seen any GIFs in MSE before that.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/would-animated-gifs-appear-noisy-here) is a prior meta discussion that generally agrees that small simple animated images with a relatively slow framerate are welcome here.  Is there also consensus in the other direction that large "noisy" fast GIFs should be hidden behind links?

Comment: If somebody is curious how often animated gifs appear in posts here, there [search for url:"*gif*"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*gif*%22) should return all posts with gifs. However, some of them may be static, some of them may be links to external sites rather than something included here. Probably a better idea is to [search this site using Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=site:math.stackexchange.com&tbs=ift:gif) and restrict the image type to gif. In this way, you get short preview - even without having to going to the post containing the picture.

Comment: Here is my animated answer... https://math.stackexchange.com/a/43005/442

Comment: Here is mine https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3269310/448 .

Answer (score 4):

In the rare cases where a GIF aids the post’s comprehensibility better than a still image could, then the GIF should remain. I’d argue your question is an example of this, although MathJax would’ve been better, had the asker tried to write the question down. Otherwise, I believe we should either make the images still, or remove them altogether.